How can I get Maven Project metadata?
I need to get metadata about Maven projects. Does it have some regisctry/api, like https://registry.npmjs.com/ for npm? Does maven even collect metadata about projects?
I know, that .pom files can be reached via https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ but it often doesn't have any metadata in it at all (like dependencies/developers/etc). I have also tried to use maven-metadata.xml but it just don't have enough data

Metadata for maven artifacts are not mandatory for the most part, but it is available where published by the creator of the artifact. For possible metadata look at the POM specification

Concerning dependency information, this is non optional, i.e. must be declared in the pom.xml. If the pom.xml does not list any dependencies, then there are none.

Are you aware that some people use parent pom's which contain contributor/developers/license.. information and not the direct pom's ... Also https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.junit/junit-bom (there are meta information?)

What sort of metadata exactly?
